# How to get Arduino UNO and WS2811 LEDs with FastSPI

Tags: arduino, led, spi

Arduino UNO and WS2811 with FASTSPI

Does anyone have any code that could help initialize the LEDs?

I literally just started learning these last night.  Got Adafruit working fine.  Don't know exactly how to set this up with FASTSPI.  But I'm trying.  Have looked everywhere.

If anyone has any code that can help get them going, it would be REALLY helpful!!!

Thanks!!
Nick

Comment: The FastSPI library comes with examples for various things including the WS2811s. I have used them successfully just a few weeks ago. Assuming you are using the new versions? https://code.google.com/p/fastspi/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks, the last place I thought to look was in the SPI's folder itself.  Thanks again!